# How to remove X-CMAE-Envelope from php mail

Tags: php, email

```
xample@gmail.com

X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4wfP8FXd8/R+a/LSU6TL5fZ2U9j6XNOlqH2ChNeZRC9M65GyLWs79yxh/WSVP1mWgmTrSR1jubA85EorlFhPmvIANJv+g8Dvba+4+i5Epzjt6Q3cuOetV2
yQT63E6PAR3l9SpC0BsxP9MXrvBLXdYDMIrGANJWNZNOR8b5focPdjP4

[Mail Message]
```

Whenever I send a mail using PHP, X-CMAE-Envelope is automatically adding in mail body. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5):

CMAE stands for Cloudmark Authority Engine and is an e-mail security product (anti-spam). This and others headers are added by this software at a server level. You should check it with your sysadmin.

https://www.cloudmark.com/en/knowledgebase/cloudmark-authority-for-spamassassin/Order-of-startup-for--CMAE-spamd-and-the-MTA

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while ago since this was asked, but if someone else gets the same problem:

I noticed that the envelope message disappears when you start the message body with an extra empty line.

\r\n\r\n Marks the end of the headers and start of the message body.

Comment: Thanks. My provider Pepipost must have changed something and were injecting the X-CMAE-Envelope incorrectly. I've padded the start of my messages with new lines and all working again as normal! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this was from a while ago but I recently had the same issue, specifically a colon ":" triggers this. But if you just start your message with \n it fixes it

Comment: Yep, both a newline at the beginning of the message fixes it, but I'm sending email to text, and that's ugly. I removed the colon from the timestamp (from `%H:%M` to `%H%M`) and it also fixes it with no need for the newline

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but I didn't find much on the web for this.

While using Python sending an email through gmail to a user@vzpix.com email, it appears the message included the X-CMAE-Envelope based on what the message was. If the message was not only text but included a date and time - then it included the X-CMAE-Envelope otherwise it was not included. With that being said, it appears server-based.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30550746)