# Python SMTPLIB remove X-CMAE-Envelope on all messages SMS

Tags: python, smtp, smtpclient, smtplib, smtp-auth

I am using SMTPLIB in python for sending sms messages and I wanted to know why some of my messages are sending with a `X-CMAE-Envelope:` header and how to remove it. I am using this python code for sending messages through sms: `

```
import smtplib


carriers = {
    'att':    '@mms.att.net',
    'tmobile':' @tmomail.net',
    'verizon':  '@vtext.com',
    'sprint':   '@messaging.sprintpcs.com',
    'alltel':   '@sms.alltelwireless.com',
    'boost':   '@sms.myboostmobile.com',
    'cricket':   '@mms.cricketwireless.net',
    'metropcs':   '@mymetropcs.com',
    'uscellular':   '@email.uscc.net',
    'virginmobile':   '@vmobl.com',
    'republicwireless':   '@text.republicwireless.com',
}

def send(message, phonenumber, phonecarrier):
    to_number = str(phonenumber + carriers['verizon'])
    auth = (EMAIL, PASSWORD)
    server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
    server.starttls()
    server.login(auth[0], auth[1])
    #msg['From'] = "TEST"
    server.sendmail(auth[0], to_number, message)


messagetext = 'Test'
send(messagetext, phonenumber, carrier)
```

Also I was wondering with sms/imessage if it is a possibility to add the contact name functionality to this code such as "siri found contact info: COMPANY NAME". Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this might help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624537/how-to-remove-x-cmae-envelope-from-php-mail  Yes, this question talks about php code, but you can apply it to your situation.

Comment: That worked thank you! About the second part with the contact info, do you think that can be accomplished?

Comment: The thing you are sending is not a valid RFC5322 message. See the [examples from the `email` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for how to create one.

Answer (score -1):

create a new line after every section of the message

email_message = f"Subject:{subject}\nTo:{carrier_emial}\n{message}."

or

message = "Subject:test\nTo:carrier_server\nmessage

Comment: This is incorrect. You should have two newlines between the headers and the body, but properly speaking, you should not be assembling email messages from simple strings yourself, especially not if you don't know exactly what you are doing.